# Effect of a variable name's length on performance and memory

Tags: objective-c, performance, memory, variables

Suppose we have two `NSString` variables (or any other class or type of data):

```
NSString* s = @"HELLO";

NSString* stringVariableWithVeryVeryVeryVeryLongName = @"HELLO";
```

Does the length of the name of a variable (the number of `char` in the variable) have an impact on performance and memory?

Answer (score 5):

No.

The compiler compiles variable names into some reference that uses the same system resources no matter what you call it.

Method names are a little bit different, in that longer method names will use a really tiny extra amount of storage, as method names need to be in the compiled code. Just never ever worry about this point, though!

Answer (score 1):

Nope (and while this is correct, SO wants me to write more...)